# RESTful API design. When request comes with a filter should you return the values for that filter too?

Tags: rest, api-design

Lets say client does GET request for /items/color/{color}

When server returns array of objects that have said color, should each item object have color property or not?

Client knows the color of returned items because he requested that color, so should server try to make a response size smaller or no?

EDIT: Can people touch more on saving bandwidth part? If it's better to return whole resource, can the answers include why it's better to return whole resource versus saving bandwidth, instead of just why whole resource should be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general (at least that's the idea of REST as I understand it), the result for the request should always be the **complete resource**. If the item contains a member `color`, there's no reason to suppress that member in the result. That would contradict the concept of resources of REST. A resource doesn't change its properties.

Suppressing members would not only come unexpected, it might even break the client when it actually expects that member.

Lets assume the client has functionality to parse the result of your REST call without a filter. All fields would be returned and the client would parse all the fields. Now the client requests the exact same resources (`item`), but suddenly the fields are different - the code from above to parse the result can not be reused.

Also, when you think about it, it's probably more work to suppress that member than to just return it.

Comment: Well, you would have documentation. If you describe this behavior and it's consistent in your api, it wouldn't really be unexpected, no?

Also, what about saving bandwidth, can you touch on that? Doesn't it matter? In web development people really care about each kb so making smaller response size thus application faster would seem to be important. The difference obviously would be bigger the bigger returned array is and the more filters there are, I would think in some cases it could be really significant.

Repeating same information client already knows in each object seems wasteful.

Comment: A resource should contain the same fields regardless of the way it is obtained, filtered or not. That's how I understand REST. Of course you're free to implement anything you want. Size does matter, but your example saves what - 20 bytes? What I'd do is: allow the client to specify the fields that should be returned. In that case the client is responsible for saving bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "correct" answer, this depends on general API design and should be your decision.

I would agree with Thorstens comment that you should return the whole resource - this is close to the general REST idea. While you do that, you can also implement some mechanism of choosing fields like in FB API: see "Choosing fields" section of [this paragraph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading).

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the color in the response. There would be multiple reasons for this:

- You make sure that what you requested for is what you get
- If there are multiple items of different colors in the page, you don't let the client take care of "filtering" the items based on colors
- You have a more "secure" response. For example, the client requests for blue color , but then a malicious script would manipulate this response as red items.

Comment: why would the client refilter the response? it was filtered server-side and client expects all items returned are "red", otherwise server code is broken

Comment: You don't have to re-filter the response, but the client has the responsibility of knowing what color are the items from the response.

Comment: the client will already send the filter data in the url `.../items/red`, so client don't have to re-check for response (is it what i asked for?)

Comment: i am not sure if you agreeing with removing the field or keep it (i say it should not be removed) any ways these points you have listed is not really convincing (with my respect to you).

Comment: Modified my answer to make it clearer, I have understood the question otherwise.

Comment: As FilipMalczak noted, there is no "correct" answer, because it is a matter of API and sometimes client design, but because of what RESTful API is, the design should take into consideration that there more types of clients, therefore send the full resource.