# How do you exclude data in an API Response to a GET call?

Tags: api, rest, postman

I am using the trefle.io api for a project. It however outputs a lot of data that I don't need and I can't seem to figure out how to exclude it from the API response. I am not looking to [query plants](https://docs.trefle.io/docs/guides/filtering/), rather prevent values from returning such as plant id, soil data, and synonyms of [the plant](https://docs.trefle.io/docs/advanced/plants-fields/#synonyms). I am currently using postman but my project will be in python. [Trefle](https://docs.trefle.io/) is a REST based API in case that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per RestAPI each endpoint describes a resource and resource has attributes . you cannot decide what attributes needs to be displayed for a resource as per standard . Its pre configured.

But as APIs are just normal programs developer can decide to have this extra functionality but for standard Rest Endpoints it will not be supported. A action on a resource returns the complete representation of the Resource .

**GraphQL** allows filtering out and displaying only certain field but for the API you use there is only RestAPI support i guess

And in the API documentation they have not provided any other endpoints which can give limited information so from the API perspective it is not possible.

But in postman you can just see the information you are interested in using visualization feature.

eg:

```
let json = pm.response.json()

delete json.data[0].synonyms
delete json.data[0].links
delete json.links
delete json.meta
json.data = [json.data[0]]
let template = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(json,null,2)}</pre>`


pm.visualizer.set(template)
```

Add this to your test script and now after sending the request got o response > body > visualize

[image]

Comment: Being able to select specific properties is certainly not a GraphQL only feature.

Comment: @Evert thanks for pointing out , ya APIs are just programs so it depends on how you program it to behave . But as per standard RestAPI returns predefined content you cannot filter out fields . But it's up to the development team to decide the functionality

Comment: "Solved: Re: Is there a way to return only certain fields t... - Canvas Community" https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Developers-Group/Is-there-a-way-to-return-only-certain-fields-through-an-API-url/m-p/121214#M2700

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40466161/6793637 there are quiet few discussions around this

Comment: there is no such thing as a 'REST Standard'. REST is a style. If you want to compare GraphQL to something, compare it to JSON:API or ODATA, which are both standards for building REST apis and support this feature.